# Vagrant error file not found grub rescue

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Before running a full release upgrade on my Ubuntu 12.04 to bring it to 14.04, I did `vagrant package --output backup.box` to backup my box.

The release upgrade did not go right, so I deleted the current box and tried to `vagrant add mybox backup.box --force` to restore to the good copy.

Instead of just restoring to the backup box, I get timeouts and 100% CPU usage for headless. I turned on the GUI and this is what I see:

```
error: file not found
grub rescue> _
```

Obviously, since this is a vagrant box I'm using on my Mac, I can't just use an Ubuntu recovery USB drive to restore.

I tried restoring from a backup from months back that I know works, but I *still* get this same grub error, which is pretty baffling.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by running `vagrant destroy` after `vagrant add mybox backup.box --force` which caused vagrant to use the newly restored box.